# Bounded Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have an inner product space H ( . , . ) over a subset $C$ and an inner product space G [ . , . ] over the same field F, if G=F then [a,b]=ab and $T \in L_b(H,G)$ denotes the set of all bounded elements of $L(H,G)$, how would I show that:

1) If $T \in L_b(H,G)$ if and only if $T\in(H,G)$?

2) $[T(\alpha),T(\alpha)] \leq K^2$ for every $\alpha \in H$ s.t. $(\alpha,\alpha)=1$

Well in order for $T \in L_b(H,G)$, T must be bounded.  But I know $T$ is bounded if $[T(\alpha),T(\alpha)] \leq K^2(\alpha,\alpha)$, but $(\alpha,\alpha)$ is equal to one so isn't it obvious then that $[T(\alpha,\alpha) \leq K^2$? For 1), I don't even know where to start to show that.  Do I need to let $T_1$ and $T_2$ and $\alpha$ be in T and show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication?